Multiple keys or shortcut keys being read when pressing shift, etc
Here is the problem,

Whenever I press the shift key it presses the Fn+low volume shortcut key.'
And when I press the caps it does the same thing but Fn+high volume.
And when I press tab it presses the del button too
And when I press the left arrow button it presses the ctrl button or the ctrl is being read whenever I press it.

I have tried every possible solution that I search and its no use, I even cleaned it, nothing happens. And for other keyboards its normal, it's just this keyboard is expensive for me. Is there any solution or do I give up on this keyboard?  It simultaneously press the other buttons when I press certain buttons.

Has it always done this?

nope, just now sir

Answer:
What you have, most likely, is a badly broken keyboard.
It will be very hard to mend using software or available knowledge.
I'd say, get a good enough spare keyboard and replace it.
For a laptop, an external USB-connected keyboard is always better then the built in one - even one for €20-30.

An attempt to explain:
Your keyboard either has bad soldering, a broken PCB or even ESD-damaged circuitry; finding all the problems and remedy them is a job that requires knowledge about the code, hardware and electronics involved.
You have no means to find out - the product is proprietary and the information is unlikely to be available anywhere where you can get it.
